# EditText not updating

Tags: android

The following forms the last portion of my `onCreate` method.

```
if (prevIntent.hasExtra("name")) {
            nameField.setText(prevIntent.getStringExtra("name"), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name = " + prevIntent.getStringExtra("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nameField = " + nameField.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The activity does dispaly `name = Some Name` and `nameField = Some Name` but what I see is the text that is defined in the layout file. Why is this happening and what can I do to make the text field show the text it's been set to show?

Comment: Is the code actually executed? Are the Toasts shown?

Comment: Yes. The code gets executed. The toasts do appear.